# stm32f7 QSPI (QUADSPI) in indirect mode can't read/write on NOR flash memory

Tags: stm32, spi, flash-memories, hal

I'm using STM32F746G-Discovery included Micron NOR flash memory n25q128a.
In CUBE example we can see this (ReadWrite_IT, Automatic polling):

```
SystemClock_Config();

  BSP_LED_Init(LED1);
  
  /* Initialize QuadSPI ------------------------------------------------------ */
  QSPIHandle.Instance = QUADSPI;
  HAL_QSPI_DeInit(&QSPIHandle);

  /* ClockPrescaler set to 2, so QSPI clock = 216MHz / (2+1) = 72MHz */
  QSPIHandle.Init.ClockPrescaler     = 2;
  QSPIHandle.Init.FifoThreshold      = 4;
  QSPIHandle.Init.SampleShifting     = QSPI_SAMPLE_SHIFTING_HALFCYCLE;
  QSPIHandle.Init.FlashSize          = POSITION_VAL(0x1000000) - 1;
  QSPIHandle.Init.ChipSelectHighTime = QSPI_CS_HIGH_TIME_2_CYCLE;
  QSPIHandle.Init.ClockMode          = QSPI_CLOCK_MODE_0;
  QSPIHandle.Init.FlashID            = QSPI_FLASH_ID_1;
  QSPIHandle.Init.DualFlash          = QSPI_DUALFLASH_DISABLE;
  
  if (HAL_QSPI_Init(&QSPIHandle) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }

  sCommand.InstructionMode   = QSPI_INSTRUCTION_1_LINE;
  sCommand.AddressSize       = QSPI_ADDRESS_24_BITS;
  sCommand.AlternateByteMode = QSPI_ALTERNATE_BYTES_NONE;
  sCommand.DdrMode           = QSPI_DDR_MODE_DISABLE;
  sCommand.DdrHoldHalfCycle  = QSPI_DDR_HHC_ANALOG_DELAY;
  sCommand.SIOOMode          = QSPI_SIOO_INST_EVERY_CMD;

  while(1)
  {
    switch(step)
    {
      case 0:
        CmdCplt = 0;
        
        /* Initialize Reception buffer --------------------------------------- */
        for (index = 0; index < BUFFERSIZE; index++)
        {
          aRxBuffer[index] = 0;
        }

        /* Enable write operations ------------------------------------------- */
        QSPI_WriteEnable(&QSPIHandle);

        /* Erasing Sequence -------------------------------------------------- */
        sCommand.Instruction = SECTOR_ERASE_CMD;
        sCommand.AddressMode = QSPI_ADDRESS_1_LINE;
        sCommand.Address     = address;
        sCommand.DataMode    = QSPI_DATA_NONE;
        sCommand.DummyCycles = 0;

        if (HAL_QSPI_Command_IT(&QSPIHandle, &sCommand) != HAL_OK)
        {
          Error_Handler();
        }

        step++;
        break;

      case 1:
        if(CmdCplt != 0)
        {
          CmdCplt = 0;
          StatusMatch = 0;

          /* Configure automatic polling mode to wait for end of erase ------- */  
          QSPI_AutoPollingMemReady(&QSPIHandle);

          step++;
        }
        break;
        
      case 2:
        if(StatusMatch != 0)
        {
          StatusMatch = 0;
          TxCplt = 0;
          
          /* Enable write operations ----------------------------------------- */
          QSPI_WriteEnable(&QSPIHandle);

          /* Writing Sequence ------------------------------------------------ */
          sCommand.Instruction = QUAD_IN_FAST_PROG_CMD;
          sCommand.AddressMode = QSPI_ADDRESS_1_LINE;
          sCommand.DataMode    = QSPI_DATA_4_LINES;
          sCommand.NbData      = BUFFERSIZE;

          if (HAL_QSPI_Command(&QSPIHandle, &sCommand, HAL_QPSI_TIMEOUT_DEFAULT_VALUE) != HAL_OK)
          {
            Error_Handler();
          }

          if (HAL_QSPI_Transmit_IT(&QSPIHandle, aTxBuffer) != HAL_OK)
          {
            Error_Handler();
          }

          step++;
        }
        break;

      case 3:
        if(TxCplt != 0)
        {
          TxCplt = 0;
          StatusMatch = 0;

          /* Configure automatic polling mode to wait for end of program ----- */  
          QSPI_AutoPollingMemReady(&QSPIHandle);
        
          step++;
        }
        break;
        
      case 4:
        if(StatusMatch != 0)
        {
          StatusMatch = 0;
          RxCplt = 0;

          /* Configure Volatile Configuration register (with new dummy cycles) */
          QSPI_DummyCyclesCfg(&QSPIHandle);
          
          /* Reading Sequence ------------------------------------------------ */
          sCommand.Instruction = QUAD_OUT_FAST_READ_CMD;
          sCommand.DummyCycles = DUMMY_CLOCK_CYCLES_READ_QUAD;

          if (HAL_QSPI_Command(&QSPIHandle, &sCommand, HAL_QPSI_TIMEOUT_DEFAULT_VALUE) != HAL_OK)
          {
            Error_Handler();
          }

          if (HAL_QSPI_Receive_IT(&QSPIHandle, aRxBuffer) != HAL_OK)
          {
            Error_Handler();
          }
          step++;
        }
        break;
        
      case 5:
        if (RxCplt != 0)
        {
          RxCplt = 0;

          /* Result comparison ----------------------------------------------- */
          for (index = 0; index < BUFFERSIZE; index++)
          {
            if (aRxBuffer[index] != aTxBuffer[index])
            {
              BSP_LED_On(LED1);
            }
          }
          BSP_LED_Toggle(LED1);

          address += QSPI_PAGE_SIZE;
          if(address >= QSPI_END_ADDR)
          {
            address = 0;
          }
          step = 0;
        }
        break;
        
      default :
        Error_Handler();
    }
  }
}

/**
  * @brief  Command completed callbacks.
  * @param  hqspi: QSPI handle
  * @retval None
  */
void HAL_QSPI_CmdCpltCallback(QSPI_HandleTypeDef *hqspi)
{
  CmdCplt++;
}

/**
  * @brief  Rx Transfer completed callbacks.
  * @param  hqspi: QSPI handle
  * @retval None
  */
void HAL_QSPI_RxCpltCallback(QSPI_HandleTypeDef *hqspi)
{
  RxCplt++;
}

/**
  * @brief  Tx Transfer completed callbacks.
  * @param  hqspi: QSPI handle
  * @retval None
  */
void HAL_QSPI_TxCpltCallback(QSPI_HandleTypeDef *hqspi)
{
  TxCplt++; 
}

/**
  * @brief  Status Match callbacks
  * @param  hqspi: QSPI handle
  * @retval None
  */
void HAL_QSPI_StatusMatchCallback(QSPI_HandleTypeDef *hqspi)
{
  StatusMatch++;
}

static void QSPI_WriteEnable(QSPI_HandleTypeDef *hqspi)
{
  QSPI_CommandTypeDef     sCommand;
  QSPI_AutoPollingTypeDef sConfig;

  /* Enable write operations ------------------------------------------ */
  sCommand.InstructionMode   = QSPI_INSTRUCTION_1_LINE;
  sCommand.Instruction       = WRITE_ENABLE_CMD;
  sCommand.AddressMode       = QSPI_ADDRESS_NONE;
  sCommand.AlternateByteMode = QSPI_ALTERNATE_BYTES_NONE;
  sCommand.DataMode          = QSPI_DATA_NONE;
  sCommand.DummyCycles       = 0;
  sCommand.DdrMode           = QSPI_DDR_MODE_DISABLE;
  sCommand.DdrHoldHalfCycle  = QSPI_DDR_HHC_ANALOG_DELAY;
  sCommand.SIOOMode          = QSPI_SIOO_INST_EVERY_CMD;

  if (HAL_QSPI_Command(&QSPIHandle, &sCommand, HAL_QPSI_TIMEOUT_DEFAULT_VALUE) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  
  /* Configure automatic polling mode to wait for write enabling ---- */  
  sConfig.Match           = 0x02;
  sConfig.Mask            = 0x02;
  sConfig.MatchMode       = QSPI_MATCH_MODE_AND;
  sConfig.StatusBytesSize = 1;
  sConfig.Interval        = 0x10;
  sConfig.AutomaticStop   = QSPI_AUTOMATIC_STOP_ENABLE;

  sCommand.Instruction    = READ_STATUS_REG_CMD;
  sCommand.DataMode       = QSPI_DATA_1_LINE;

  if (HAL_QSPI_AutoPolling(&QSPIHandle, &sCommand, &sConfig, HAL_QPSI_TIMEOUT_DEFAULT_VALUE) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
}

/**
  * @brief  This function reads the SR of the memory and awaits the EOP.
  * @param  hqspi: QSPI handle
  * @retval None
  */
static void QSPI_AutoPollingMemReady(QSPI_HandleTypeDef *hqspi)
{
  QSPI_CommandTypeDef     sCommand;
  QSPI_AutoPollingTypeDef sConfig;

  /* Configure automatic polling mode to wait for memory ready ------ */  
  sCommand.InstructionMode   = QSPI_INSTRUCTION_1_LINE;
  sCommand.Instruction       = READ_STATUS_REG_CMD;
  sCommand.AddressMode       = QSPI_ADDRESS_NONE;
  sCommand.AlternateByteMode = QSPI_ALTERNATE_BYTES_NONE;
  sCommand.DataMode          = QSPI_DATA_1_LINE;
  sCommand.DummyCycles       = 0;
  sCommand.DdrMode           = QSPI_DDR_MODE_DISABLE;
  sCommand.DdrHoldHalfCycle  = QSPI_DDR_HHC_ANALOG_DELAY;
  sCommand.SIOOMode         = QSPI_SIOO_INST_EVERY_CMD;

  sConfig.Match           = 0x00;
  sConfig.Mask            = 0x01;
  sConfig.MatchMode       = QSPI_MATCH_MODE_AND;
  sConfig.StatusBytesSize = 1;
  sConfig.Interval        = 0x10;
  sConfig.AutomaticStop   = QSPI_AUTOMATIC_STOP_ENABLE;

  if (HAL_QSPI_AutoPolling_IT(&QSPIHandle, &sCommand, &sConfig) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
}

/**
  * @brief  This function configures the dummy cycles on memory side.
  * @param  hqspi: QSPI handle
  * @retval None
  */
static void QSPI_DummyCyclesCfg(QSPI_HandleTypeDef *hqspi)
{
  QSPI_CommandTypeDef sCommand;
  uint8_t reg;

  /* Read Volatile Configuration register --------------------------- */
  sCommand.InstructionMode   = QSPI_INSTRUCTION_1_LINE;
  sCommand.Instruction       = READ_VOL_CFG_REG_CMD;
  sCommand.AddressMode       = QSPI_ADDRESS_NONE;
  sCommand.AlternateByteMode = QSPI_ALTERNATE_BYTES_NONE;
  sCommand.DataMode          = QSPI_DATA_1_LINE;
  sCommand.DummyCycles       = 0;
  sCommand.DdrMode           = QSPI_DDR_MODE_DISABLE;
  sCommand.DdrHoldHalfCycle  = QSPI_DDR_HHC_ANALOG_DELAY;
  sCommand.SIOOMode         = QSPI_SIOO_INST_EVERY_CMD;
  sCommand.NbData            = 1;

  if (HAL_QSPI_Command(&QSPIHandle, &sCommand, HAL_QPSI_TIMEOUT_DEFAULT_VALUE) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }

  if (HAL_QSPI_Receive(&QSPIHandle, &reg, HAL_QPSI_TIMEOUT_DEFAULT_VALUE) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }

  /* Enable write operations ---------------------------------------- */
  QSPI_WriteEnable(&QSPIHandle);

  /* Write Volatile Configuration register (with new dummy cycles) -- */  
  sCommand.Instruction = WRITE_VOL_CFG_REG_CMD;
  MODIFY_REG(reg, 0xF0, (DUMMY_CLOCK_CYCLES_READ_QUAD << POSITION_VAL(0xF0)));

  if (HAL_QSPI_Command(&QSPIHandle, &sCommand, HAL_QPSI_TIMEOUT_DEFAULT_VALUE) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }

  if (HAL_QSPI_Transmit(&QSPIHandle, &reg, HAL_QPSI_TIMEOUT_DEFAULT_VALUE) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
}
```

And this works just fine (LED start blinking and debugger watch of TXbuffer agree that the works fine) in Automatic polling mode. But I don't want to trigger any interrupt, then I've tried to convert it to polling, blocking, indirect mode. It seems it must works by just removing `_IT` suffix from all function including it. Also by removing every function that included `polling` in it's name.
At first move I start to removing every _IT then trasmission and recption suffix removed without problem but removing _IT suffix from HAL_QSPI_AutoPolling_IT will cause the rxbuff filled with zero (I was aware to place variable++ command associated with their Interrupt handler named `TxCplt`,`RxCplt`,`StatusMatch`).

Any Idea?

Comment: You're using lower clock prescaler in the non-working code (1 instead of 2), i.e. higher clock frequency. Tried slowing it down?

Comment: @Klas-Kenny Oh I've tried as you said but also doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Commenting QSPI_AutoPollingMemReady(&QSPIHandle); which included `HAL_QSPI_AutoPolling_IT` caused to completely solve the problem, and in my custom code I've forgotten to remap the QSPI pin as defined in STM32F746-Disc schematic.