# STM32F746G-Disc code examining QSPI flash data transfer consecutively fail/pass by resetting MCU

Tags: stm32, spi

Programming STM32F746 MCU with below code (read and write, then compare on N25Q128A NOR flash memory) result change after each time resetting MCU by it's botton or under debug session:

```
int main(void)
{

  /* USER CODE BEGIN 1 */

  /* USER CODE END 1 */

  /* MCU Configuration--------------------------------------------------------*/

  /* Reset of all peripherals, Initializes the Flash interface and the Systick. */
  HAL_Init();

  /* USER CODE BEGIN Init */

  /* USER CODE END Init */

  /* Configure the system clock */
  SystemClock_Config();

  /* USER CODE BEGIN SysInit */

  /* USER CODE END SysInit */

  /* Initialize all configured peripherals */
  MX_GPIO_Init();
  MX_QUADSPI_Init();
  /* USER CODE BEGIN 2 */

  QSPI_CommandTypeDef sCommand;
  uint32_t address = 0;
  uint8_t BUFFERSIZE=20;
  uint8_t txbuf[20]={1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20};
  uint8_t rxbuf[20]={0};

//  QSPI_ResetMemory(&hqspi);
//  HAL_Delay(100);


  sCommand.InstructionMode   = QSPI_INSTRUCTION_1_LINE;
  sCommand.AddressSize       = QSPI_ADDRESS_24_BITS;
  sCommand.AlternateByteMode = QSPI_ALTERNATE_BYTES_NONE;
  sCommand.DdrMode           = QSPI_DDR_MODE_DISABLE;
  sCommand.DdrHoldHalfCycle  = QSPI_DDR_HHC_ANALOG_DELAY;
  sCommand.SIOOMode          = QSPI_SIOO_INST_EVERY_CMD;


  QSPI_DummyCyclesCfg(&hqspi);

/*******Erase sequence*********/
  QSPI_WriteEnable(&hqspi);
  sCommand.Instruction = SECTOR_ERASE_CMD;
  sCommand.AddressMode = QSPI_ADDRESS_1_LINE;
  sCommand.Address     = address;
  sCommand.DataMode    = QSPI_DATA_NONE;
  sCommand.DummyCycles = 0;
  HAL_QSPI_Command(&hqspi, &sCommand,HAL_QPSI_TIMEOUT_DEFAULT_VALUE);
  HAL_Delay(100);//HAL_QSPI_Abort(&hqspi);
  /***********Transmission sequence***********/
  QSPI_WriteEnable(&hqspi);
//  HAL_Delay(50);//HAL_QSPI_Abort(&hqspi);
  sCommand.Instruction = QUAD_IN_FAST_PROG_CMD;
  sCommand.AddressMode = QSPI_ADDRESS_1_LINE;
  sCommand.DataMode    = QSPI_DATA_4_LINES;
  sCommand.NbData      = BUFFERSIZE;
  HAL_QSPI_Command(&hqspi, &sCommand, HAL_QPSI_TIMEOUT_DEFAULT_VALUE);HAL_Delay(100);
  HAL_QSPI_Transmit(&hqspi, txbuf,1000000);
  HAL_Delay(40);//HAL_QSPI_Abort(&hqspi);
  /***********Reception sequence***********/
//  QSPI_DummyCyclesCfg(&hqspi);
  sCommand.Instruction = QUAD_OUT_FAST_READ_CMD;
  sCommand.DummyCycles = DUMMY_CLOCK_CYCLES_READ_QUAD;
  //sCommand.NbData      = BUFFERSIZE;
  HAL_QSPI_Command(&hqspi, &sCommand, HAL_QPSI_TIMEOUT_DEFAULT_VALUE);
  HAL_QSPI_Receive(&hqspi, (uint8_t*)rxbuf,1000000);
  HAL_Delay(100);
  HAL_Delay(1);
//  HAL_Delay(100);//HAL_QSPI_Abort(&hqspi);

  /************Test result********/
  uint8_t index=0;
  for (index = 0; index < BUFFERSIZE; index++)
            {
              if (rxbuf[index] != txbuf[index])
              {
                HAL_GPIO_WritePin(LED_GPIO_Port,LED_Pin,GPIO_PIN_SET);
              }
            }
  /* USER CODE END 2 */

  /* Infinite loop */
  /* USER CODE BEGIN WHILE */
  while (1)
  {
    /* USER CODE END WHILE */

    /* USER CODE BEGIN 3 */
  }
  /* USER CODE END 3 */
}

static void QSPI_WriteEnable(QSPI_HandleTypeDef *hqspi)
{
  QSPI_CommandTypeDef     sCommand;
  QSPI_AutoPollingTypeDef sConfig;

  /* Enable write operations ------------------------------------------ */
  sCommand.InstructionMode   = QSPI_INSTRUCTION_1_LINE;
  sCommand.Instruction       = WRITE_ENABLE_CMD;
  sCommand.AddressMode       = QSPI_ADDRESS_NONE;
  sCommand.AlternateByteMode = QSPI_ALTERNATE_BYTES_NONE;
  sCommand.DataMode          = QSPI_DATA_NONE;
  sCommand.DummyCycles       = 0;
  sCommand.DdrMode           = QSPI_DDR_MODE_DISABLE;
  sCommand.DdrHoldHalfCycle  = QSPI_DDR_HHC_ANALOG_DELAY;
  sCommand.SIOOMode          = QSPI_SIOO_INST_EVERY_CMD;

  if (HAL_QSPI_Command(hqspi, &sCommand, HAL_QPSI_TIMEOUT_DEFAULT_VALUE) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }

  /* Configure automatic polling mode to wait for write enabling ---- */
  sConfig.Match           = 0x02;
  sConfig.Mask            = 0x02;
  sConfig.MatchMode       = QSPI_MATCH_MODE_AND;
  sConfig.StatusBytesSize = 1;
  sConfig.Interval        = 0x10;
  sConfig.AutomaticStop   = QSPI_AUTOMATIC_STOP_ENABLE;

  sCommand.Instruction    = READ_STATUS_REG_CMD;
  sCommand.DataMode       = QSPI_DATA_1_LINE;

//  if (HAL_QSPI_AutoPolling(hqspi, &sCommand, &sConfig, HAL_QPSI_TIMEOUT_DEFAULT_VALUE) != HAL_OK)
//  {
//    Error_Handler();
//  }
}

/***********************************************/

static void QSPI_DummyCyclesCfg(QSPI_HandleTypeDef *QSPIHandle)
{
  QSPI_CommandTypeDef sCommand;
  uint8_t reg;

  /* Read Volatile Configuration register --------------------------- */
  sCommand.InstructionMode   = QSPI_INSTRUCTION_1_LINE;
  sCommand.Instruction       = READ_VOL_CFG_REG_CMD;
  sCommand.AddressMode       = QSPI_ADDRESS_NONE;
  sCommand.AlternateByteMode = QSPI_ALTERNATE_BYTES_NONE;
  sCommand.DataMode          = QSPI_DATA_1_LINE;
  sCommand.DummyCycles       = 0;
  sCommand.DdrMode           = QSPI_DDR_MODE_DISABLE;
  sCommand.DdrHoldHalfCycle  = QSPI_DDR_HHC_ANALOG_DELAY;
  sCommand.SIOOMode         = QSPI_SIOO_INST_EVERY_CMD;
  sCommand.NbData            = 1;

  if (HAL_QSPI_Command(QSPIHandle, &sCommand, HAL_QPSI_TIMEOUT_DEFAULT_VALUE) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }

  if (HAL_QSPI_Receive(QSPIHandle, &reg, HAL_QPSI_TIMEOUT_DEFAULT_VALUE) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }

  /* Enable write operations ---------------------------------------- */
  QSPI_WriteEnable(QSPIHandle);//optional

  /* Write Volatile Configuration register (with new dummy cycles) -- */
  sCommand.Instruction = WRITE_VOL_CFG_REG_CMD;
  MODIFY_REG(reg, 0xF0, (DUMMY_CLOCK_CYCLES_READ_QUAD << POSITION_VAL(0xF0)));

  if (HAL_QSPI_Command(QSPIHandle, &sCommand, HAL_QPSI_TIMEOUT_DEFAULT_VALUE) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }

  if (HAL_QSPI_Transmit(QSPIHandle, &reg, HAL_QPSI_TIMEOUT_DEFAULT_VALUE) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  HAL_Delay( 40 );
}
```

Actually in first run rxbuff fills correctly after reset it returns just 1 on every bit but after reset again everything is ok and it repeats!!

I've doubled receive commands and buy debugging understood that unprogrammed bytes are all 1 and maybe the program or write commands are not working after each they execute correctly at the same address.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The datasheet says sector erase can take up to 3 seconds, so yes, obviously 100ms or even 400ms may not be enough.

Either, use a long enough delay, or, poll when the operation is complete, maybe with timeout to see if an operation fails.

Comment: Could you please mention your opinion about https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/603868/stm32f7-qspi-quadspi-in-indirect-mode-cant-read-write-on-nor-flash-memory too?

Answer (score 0):

After erasing sequence `HAL_Delay(400);` has been placed and problem has been vanished. It mean erasing operasion was needing more time!